# Correct way to emulate single precision floating point in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

What's the best way to emulate single-precision floating point in python?  (Or other floating point formats for that matter?)  Just use ctypes?

Comment: What do you mean by "emulate"?  Read floats from binary blobs?  Execute math in single-precision and get the same results as another language?  (If the latter, note that "float" math in C on x86 is actually evaluated in 80-bit and reduced to 32-bit when it's stored.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) package has a [`float32`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html?highlight=float32#array-types-and-conversions-between-types) type.

Answer (score 19):

If `numpy` (the excellent suggestion of other answers) is inapplicable for you (e.g. because you're in an environment that doesn't allow arbitrary third-party extensions), the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array) module in Python standard library is fine too -- type code `'f'` gives you 32-bit floats.  Besides those and the (usual) double precision floats, there isn't much for "other floating point formats" -- what did you have in mind?  (e.g. `gmpy` offers GMP's modest support for floats with much longer, arbitrary bit sizes -- but it's modest indeed, e.g., no trig functions).

Comment: Nowadays, [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mpfr.html) has much more complete support for floats through MPFR.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use Python's `struct` module to truncate a 64-bit float to the precision of a 32-bit float.

For example:

```
>>> x = 1.1122334455667788
>>> x
1.1122334455667788
>>> struct.unpack('f', struct.pack('f', x))[0]
1.1122334003448486
```

To do arithmetic only with 32-bit floats, you would need to apply this truncation operation to the result of every arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 9):

how about ctypes.c_float from standard library?

Comment: This works, but math operations are harder, compared to `numpy` which defines operations and propagates precision like other common programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

If your application suits arrays/matrices, you can use numpy with `float32`

Answer (score 2):

To expand a little on the `ctypes` option [1]:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)                                                                                                                                                        
4
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_long)                                                                                                                                                       
8

>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)                                                                                                                                                      
4
>>> ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_double)                                                                                                                                                     
8
```

With numpy [2], e.g.:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='uint8').nbytes                                                                                                                                              
1
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='uint16').nbytes                                                                                                                                             
2
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='uint64').nbytes                                                                                                                                             
8
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='float').nbytes  # watch out for this one
8
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='float32').nbytes                                                                                                                                            
4
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='float64').nbytes                                                                                                                                            
8
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='single').nbytes                                                                                                                                             
4
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='double').nbytes                                                                                                                                             
8
```

numpy.astype does conversions, e.g.

```
>>> np.zeros((1,1), dtype='double').astype('single').nbytes                                                                                                                            
4
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types

[2] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html