# Does Python have 32 bit float primitive data type?

Tags: python, floating-point

In Java, there is `float` and `double` where float is a 32 bit primitive data type for decimals and double is a 64 bit primitive data type for decimals.  From what I understand, Python's `float` is actually 64 bits.  I've seen the class `Numpy`, but is there a primitive data type in Python that has 32 bits?

Comment: Why would you want this? If memory overhead is a problem, python is the wrong language for you. And more precision is always good

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2232650/

Comment: It was a question out of curiosity.  I've seen it one language, and just wondered if it was in another.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: More precision isn't always good, though.