# Iterating over Pandas dataframe using zip and df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over a df to calculate values for a new column, but it's taking too long. Here is the code (it's been simplified for brevity):

```
def calculate(row):
    values = []
    weights = []
    continued = False

    df_a = df[((df.winner_id == row['winner_id']) | (df.loser_id == row['winner_id']))].loc[row['index'] + 1:]
    if len(df_a) < 30:
        df.drop(row['index'], inplace = True)    
        continued = True
    ##if we dropped the row, we don't want to calculate it's value
    if continued == False:
        for match in zip(df_a['winner_id'],df_a['tourney_date'],df_a['winner_rank'],df_a['loser_rank'],
                         df_a['winner_serve_pts_pct']):
                weight = time_discount(yrs_between(match[1],row['tourney_date']))
                ##calculate individual values and weights
                values.append(match[4] * weight * opp_weight(match[3]))
                weights.append(weight)
    ##return calculated value
    return sum(values)/sum(weights)


df['new'] = df.apply(calculate, axis = 1)
```

My dataframe is not too large (60,000 by 35), but it's taking about 40 minutes for my code to run. I originally used iterrows(), but people suggested that I use zip() and apply - but it's still taking very long. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: No, rounding floats does not affect performance. If you want a speedup you have to optimize your code.

Comment: You could multiply them by e.g. 1000 and then convert them to integers. Depending on the range of your values that might use less memory.

Comment: Given an array that is probably bigger than the fastest layers in the memory hierarchy, the order in which you access it will make a big difference in performance. For example, there are strategies for speeding up matrix multiplication by changing the order of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It is very rare for the performance of floating point operations on large arrays to be limited by the actual computation. It is much commoner for the limiting factor to be cache sizes and getting numbers to and from the floating point registers and arithmetic unit.

If you can accept reduced precision, you may get some benefit from going to 32 bit floats instead of the default 64 bit. That will halve the size of your arrays. See [Correct way to emulate single precision floating point in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232362/correct-way-to-emulate-single-precision-floating-point-in-python)

It will still leave you with a 9,600,000 byte data structure, larger than the critical low level caches where you need to fit your active data.

A better approach may be to look at organizing the order of your operations to make efficient use of caches. For example, matrix multiplication can be optimized by regarding it as the sum of a series of multiplications of smaller sub-matrices, each of which fits in caches. Making whether you iterate along rows or columns match how your array is stored in memory can make a big difference.

In general, focus your attention on minimizing data movement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried minimising data movement by only using necessary columns (i.e. by using zip()).

Comment: @Mathboy The order of memory accesses matters a lot. Each time the processor does not find the number it needs in cache, it brings in a whole cache line, containing several consecutive words. If you use those words soon, they will not cause another cache miss.